Не вычисляется интеграл
from sympy import symbols, sqrt, integrate

x = symbols('x')
f = (sqrt(1 + x**2) + sqrt(1 - x**2)) / sqrt(1 - x**4)
integral = integrate(f, x)

print(integral)

Я не понимаю, почему в случае функции f = (sqrt(1 + x^2) + sqrt(1 - x^2)) / sqrt(1 - x^4) программа не считает интеграл. До этого все ответы сходились.
На этот раз программа выдает результат:
Integral((sqrt(1 - x^2) + sqrt(x^2 + 1))/sqrt(-(x - 1)*(x + 1)*(x^2 + 1)), x)

Хотя должно быть:
arcsin(x)+ln(x+sqrt(1+x^2))


Мне сперва производную стоит вычислить, а потом от нее взять интеграл?

Проблема в питоне и его библиотеках? Если дифференцировать вручную, то все сходится.

Вы правы. После замены x = symbols('x', real=True) sympy дифференцирует ваш пример и производная равна выражению под интегралом. При этом integrate не работает.

а что сделать чтобы integrate  работало? или в данном случае лучше использовать другую библиотеку?

У меня, кажется, получилось вывести требуемый ответ. Я упростила интегрируемое выражение:

# Создаем символьную переменную
x = symbols('x')
#Задаем функцию упростив
f = 1/sqrt(1 + x**2) + 1/sqrt(1 - x**2)
#считаем интеграл
integral = integrate(f, x)

print(integral, '+C')

Теперь программа дает результат asin(x) + asinh(x) +C. Но почему она не работает с неупрощенным выражением?
